# What is ExptDemo (Delphi 7 using GExperts)?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, gexperts

Am using Delphi 7 for an old project with GExperts 1.36. There are a bunch of interesting options, one of which is the `Expert Manager`. My installation shows three entries (see image).

[image: GExperts list of experts showing ExptDemo]

`DelphiSpeedUp` is used to load the IDE more quickly.

`GExperts` is the productivity tool this question is using.

But I have no idea what `ExptDemo` is and cannot find any information either in the Delphi or GExperts help or on the web. Can anyone help? Is this useful and is there any harm in disabling or deleting this expert?

Comment: What problems are you facing?

Comment: How are we to know what unknown expert you've installed on your system?

Comment: @Ken to be fair I think it's a Borland example

Comment: @David: It's not in D2007 and above; see the Demos\DelphiWin32\VCLWin32\ToolAPI folder. Those are the samples that were in D7, IIRC (although they were in a different samples folder). If it's a Borland example, then the poster should be able to find the source and figure out what it is by searching the drive.

Comment: @KenWhite It's present in my D6 bin directory, but I can't obviously find the source

Comment: The specific problem I had was instability when using the GExperts Grep Search (a crash in a Borland DLL, I forget which). No idea why. Maybe the IDE had been running for too long (several days) and the Grep search cache was getting full? I don't know, a reboot solved the problem. Anyway, I started looking into the GExperts settings and came across this. It was not installed by me, at least not as far as I know. This question is just `Oh, that's interesting. What is this? Cannot find any information about this anywhere.` not related to my earlier problem.

Comment: You can look in the registry to see if you can find info, in either the Borland or GExperts keys in HKCU\Software. You should find a listing for it in one of them, which may give you a clue where it comes from and what it is,

Comment: @KenWhite: Good thought. A registry search for `ExptDemo` finds two references at `[HKCU\Software\Borland\Delphi\7.0\Experts]` and `[HKLM\SOFTWARE\Borland\Delphi\7.0\Experts]`. Both mention the name of the expert and the DLL (as in the image) but nothing else.

Comment: Does the dll have any version information?

Comment: No, unfortuantely not. When you right-click and choose properties, there is no `Version` tab.